# Servidor não pode anexar um cabeçalho após os cabeçalhos HTTP terem sido enviados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gzip

Bom dia,

Tenho o seguinte código que uso pra comprimir os controllers usando o `GZip`.

Faço o login no sistema normalmente, porém se eu tento trocar de empresa logada o seguinte erro é apresentado:

> Servidor não pode anexar um cabeçalho após os cabeçalhos HTTP terem sido enviados

Erro na linha:

```js
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

Código usado para compressão:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EngemanMVC.MLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute that can be added to controller methods to force content
    /// to be GZip encoded if the client supports it
    /// </summary>
    public class CompressContentAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Override to compress the content that is generated by
        /// an action method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            GZipEncodePage();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if GZip is supported
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsGZipSupported()
        {
            string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) &&
                    (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || AcceptEncoding.Contains("deflate")))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up the current page or handler to use GZip through a Response.Filter
        /// IMPORTANT:  
        /// You have to call this method before any output is generated!
        /// </summary>
        public static void GZipEncodePage()
        {
            HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            if (IsGZipSupported())
            {
                string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

                if (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    if (Response.Filter != null)
                    {
                        Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(Response.Filter,
                                                    System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                        Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Encoding");
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Response.Filter != null)
                    {
                        Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(Response.Filter,
                                                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                        Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Encoding");
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                    }
                }


            }

            // Allow proxy servers to cache encoded and unencoded versions separately
            Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Content-Encoding");
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: Se eu continuar o programa funciona normalmente, porém queria evitar colocar um try/catch vazio por não ser recomendável nem bonito.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você troca de empresa redirecionando a página? se sim, qual método você utiliza? Response.Redirect(url) ou apenas Redirect(url) ?

Comment: O logout é simplesmente um `window.location.href`para o login, onde ao chamar a action do controller, as sessions são limpas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema acontece, porque ao redirecionar a página via `window.location.href`é realizado o redirect na página mais os cabeçalhos da requisição são mantidos, o que você deve fazer é tentar antes de redirecionar a página, é limpar os headers da requisição, quando a página for carregada novamente ela virá sem os cabeçalhos de compactação.

Provavelmente o método `window.location.href` está sendo executado diretamente no código da página. Como vc colocou a tag ASP.NET MVC tente ao invés de chamar o código de relocação na página usar um método no controller para redirecionamento, mais ou menos como descrito abaixo:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    Response.Redirect("/login");// Aqui vai a página para qual quer ser redirecionado
}
```

Desta forma quando a requisição passar para a outra página ela irá com os cabeçalhos limpos. possibilitando assim o uso da compactação.